# Threads with PySimpleGui gives RunTimeError

Tags: python, multithreading, pysimplegui

I have explored using threads with PySimpleGui but quite often the thread terminates

```
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

I have tried running the "official" demos, forexample:

https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Multithreaded_Long_Task_Simple.py

This gives me the runtime error when I run it locally. However when I run the same demo on trinket :

https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/multi-threaded/multi-threaded-long-task-simple

It seems to run fine. I am using

windows 10
Anaconda
python 3.8
spyder 4.2 (IDLE)

I have also tried to run outside spyder (IDLE) with the same effect.

Full error message:

```
*Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs\python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs\python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\xxxx\Demo_Multithreaded_Long_Task_Simple.py", line 31, in long_operation_thread
    window.write_event_value('-PROGRESS-', progress)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs\python38\lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 8940, in write_event_value
    self.thread_strvar.set('new item')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.conda\envs\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 365, in set
    return self._tk.globalsetvar(self._name, value)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop*`
```

Comment: What version of PySimpleGUI ?

Comment: Hi Jason it is:

"4.32.1 Released 17-Nov-2020"

Comment: It's a horrible, unfortunate turn of events.  What I was told was THE single thread-safe tkinter call I could make has turned out not to be theadsafe.  I need to see how I can get around this.  The OLD version of multi-threading may have to be used in the meantime.  This way is to post a message in a queue and then run your event loop with a timeout that will check this queue.

Comment: What happens when you run from the command line (Not IDLE)? Python3 app.py

Comment: Hi MikeyB

I tried to run it from command line ( python.exe Demo_Multithreaded_Long_Task_Simple.py) . Here i get the same error message after a while.